# Why the LIKE in SQL Server and FindString in SSIS return different row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-like

I am trying to load a web log data into my SQL Server database. One of my column contains an url link, for example

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=why%
```

I need to load rows contain "questions" string in the url column only.

In my SSIS package, I use conditional split with condition:

```
FINDSTRING(url, "questions", 1) >= 1.
```

I got 500 rows.

However, when I try to confirm it in the database with the following condition:

```
where url like '%questions%'
```

I got 530 rows.

I though this two conditions are equivalent and should return same number of rows. Can anyone help me point out what are the difference between these filters? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok..one difference you can find is

Ex URL: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=why%"

so doing a like :

```
select * from table where column like '%/questions/%'

doing  FINDSTRING(url,"/questions/",1)=1
```

should give you exact results !

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is case sensitive, whereas your SQL query is likely being evaluated in a case insensitive fashion.

Try `FINDSTRING(LOWER(url), "questions", 1) >= 1`

Or, if you prefer the SSIS answer, try `where url like '%questions%' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS`